# Power BI DAX with filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to Power BI and DAX. I have a table that looks something like the one below
[image]

I want to create a DAX measure to put on a card visualization; when I filter the page for a user name, it should display the AVERAGE of the value by department.
For e.g. in this case if I filter by User 1 (department = Legal), I should get the average of three values for user 1 and two values for User 3 which in this case would be (0.255836 + 0.209221 + 0.326591 + 0.212668 + 0.191183)/5 = 0.2391

I tried using CALCULATE(AVERAGE(mytablename[value]), REMOVEFILTERS(tablename[username])) but this doesn't seem to work. How should I go about this?

Comment: If you already filter the user in the page, it is as if your tables only contain that user. So if you want the average of just that user, you should get it with the average. You don't need removefilters.

Comment: Hey @AdrianFischer - I want the average of the values for the department the user belongs to. Here, User 1 belongs to the Legal department and hence when the filter is set to user 1, I want the average for all of the members in the legal department. When filter is set to User 2, I want the average for all of the users in the HR department (as user 2 belongs to the HR department) and so on. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there. Simply remove all filters, and re-apply the selected department filter context::

```
Departmental Average Value = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        AVERAGE ( MyTable[Value] ),
        REMOVEFILTERS (MyTable),
        MyTable[Department] = SELECTEDVALUE ( MyTable[Department] )
    )
```

Comment: I had to use a combination of both the approaches above to get to my desired result. Thank you Olly and Adrian for you help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is this one:

```
AverageDpt = 
    var Cat = FIRSTNONBLANK(mytablename[Department],True)
return
    CALCULATE(AVERAGE(mytablename[Value]),filter(ALL(mytablename),mytablename[Department]=Cat))
```

**Explanation**

1. With the variable Cat you get the name of the department.
2. In the Calculate function:
   2.1 `All(mytablename)`: removes all filters
   2.2 `mytablename[Department]=Cat)`: filters only those rows with the right department

**Alternative**
If, in case you need it to show the normal average if no user has been selected, you can use this code:

```
AverageDpt = 
    var Cat = FIRSTNONBLANK(mytablename[Department],True)
    var DistCount = DISTINCTCOUNT(mytablename[Department])
return
    if (DistCount=1,
        CALCULATE(AVERAGE(mytablename[Value]),filter(ALL(mytablename),mytablename[Department]=Cat)),
        AVERAGE(mytablename[Value]))
```

This is the result I get:
[image]

Comment: Adrian, thank you. Let me try this, I think this should work, will mark your answer / let you know if this doesn't work. Thanks again.